# Creating a rechecking if statement

Tags: java

I'm doing a grade average script for my class and I can't figure how to get my cross check section to repeat until I have a valid value (Code is listed below).  When ran, it allows me to make the correction if the original input is invalid but does this only once.  How can I loop until I get a proper response?  Thanks in advance!

```
  if (grade1 >= 0 && grade1 <= 100)
     System.out.println("First grade valid.\n");
  else
     {
        System.out.println("Grade invalid.  Re-enter first grade:");
        grade1 = kb.nextDouble();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

consider

```
grade = -1;
System.out.println("Enter a grade:\n");
grade1 = kb.nextDouble();
if (grade1 >= 0 && grade1 <= 100)
{
    System.out.println("First grade valid.\n");
}
else
{
    while (grade1 < 0 || grade1 > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Grade invalid.  Re-enter first grade:");
        grade1 = kb.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried that edit, and it negates the ability to re-enter.

Comment: You are supposed to have the re-entry code inside the loop. Please post the loop showing how you refactored it with FredK's suggestion. Simply posting "it doesn't work" fails to provide enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Chara, as the method executed originally, I setup it up so user plugs in their inputs and cross checks the validity after they've been entered using the (first excerpt below).  Figured it would to save the space if I could just actively cross check upon initial input (see second excerpt below).  Lew Bloch, I understand what you getting at and was a slight oversight on my part and I will do better in my response from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ((grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a grade"))) < 0 || grade > 100) {
    System.out.println("Invalid grade of: " + grade);
}
```

It doesnt handle letters nicely though, if you enter "a" itll complain and yell at you

Answer (score 0):

Chara, as the method executed originally, I setup it up so user plugs in their inputs and cross checks the validity after they've been entered (see first excerpt below).  Figured it would be best to save the space if I could just actively cross check upon initial input (see second excerpt below).  Lew Bloch, I understand what you are getting at and this was a slight oversight on my part. I will do better in my responses from now on.

// Cross Check

```
  if (grade1 >= 0 && grade1 <= 100)
     System.out.println("First grade valid.\n");
  else
     {
        System.out.println("Grade invalid.  Re-enter first grade:");
        grade1 = kb.nextDouble();
     }
```

// Grade entry

```
  grade1 = kb.nextDouble();
  while (grade1 < 0 || grade1 > 100)
  {
     System.out.println("Entered grade is invalid.  Re-enter grade:");
     grade1 = kb.nextDouble();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Enter a grade:\n");
    double grade1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    if (grade1 >= 0 && grade1 <= 100)
    {
        System.out.println("First grade valid.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (grade1 < 0 || grade1 > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade invalid.  Re-enter first grade:");
            grade1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```